# <AuthorizeView> works when running locally in Visual Studio but not on IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-authentication, blazor

I created a new Blazor server side application using Visual Studio 2019. I selected Windows authentication.

The following component (`\BlazorApp1\BlazorApp1\Shared\LoginDisplay.razor`) displays "Hello, Domain\Username!" on the top right of the page in the browser in the application.

```
<AuthorizeView>
    Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!
</AuthorizeView>
```

Then I publish it to IIS on Windows Server 2019 R2 in the same Windows domain (Company intranet network). However, browsing the page doesn't show the message in ?

How is the client authentication information passed to the Blazer server?

Comment: I may be wrong, but it works locally because server and browser are running in same domain/network. I guess server where the app is later deployed and browser from which you are accessing the app are in different. Isn't it?

Comment: They are all in the same Windows domain.

Comment: Have you enabled windows authentication and disable anonymous authentication for your IIS Server? The message will show only when I enable windows authentication. If I just enable anonymous authentication,  Even "hello" will not be displayed

Comment: I have the same issue - AuthorizeView does not work on IIS under windows auth but does locally

Answer (score -1):

There is good example on Microsoft docs for getting authentication user details:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider

<button @onclick="@LogUsername">Write user info to console</button>

@code {
    private async Task LogUsername()
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{user.Identity.Name} is authenticated.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The user is NOT authenticated.");
        }
    }
}
```

To answer

> How is the client authentication information passed to the Blazer
>   server?

If authentication state data is required for procedural logic, such as when performing an action triggered by the user, obtain the authentication state data by defining a cascading parameter of type Task:

```
@page "/"

<button @onclick="@LogUsername">Log username</button>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    private async Task LogUsername()
    {
        var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{user.Identity.Name} is authenticated.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The user is NOT authenticated.");
        }
    }
}
```

for details refer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: You are not answering the question... The OP wants to know how the authentication state is routed to a Blazor App, not how it is used in the Blazor App. And she wants to know how it is done in the context of Windows Authentication. Your answer as well as the docs do not provide any useful information about this.